# how to navigate through an anchor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, anchor

I have 'cancel' and 'next' at the bottom of my view.
'Next' posts the details back to the controller. But I would like 'cancel', not as a button but just as plain text to return to the previous page.

```
<li class="align left"><a href="#">@T("Cancel")</a></li>
<li class="align right"><button type="submit">@T("Next")</button></li>
```

can I do it from the view? or do I have to change it to a button and post back, then use the post back to navigate from the controller?

Iv tried adding #URL to href tag. but this adds URL onto existing, instead of new URL

```
<li class="align left"><a href="#http://URL/">@T("Cancel")</a></li>
```

Comment: Try `<a href='@Url.Action("ActionName")'>@T("Cancel")</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With Html Helpers**

I think you just want to use an [`ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)...

```
@Html.ActionLink("text for link", "ActionName", "ControllerName")
```

If you need any parameters for the Action then use this overload instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("text for link", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { @p1 = 1, @p2 = 2 }, null)
```

Note that the final parameter in that overload (which I set as `null`) can be used to set html attributes for the generated `<a>` tag. For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("text for link", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { @p1 = 1, @p2 = 2 }, new { @class = "MyClass" })
```

---

**With Plain Html**

Your attempt to use plain html should also work, providing you remove the `#` from the start of the `href` value:

```
<a href="http://URL/">@T("Cancel")</a>
```

(not really sure what your `T()` function is, but it doesn't matter)

Alternatively, rather than specifying a hard-coded url, you can dynamically generate the correct URL based on an Action name (thanks to codingbiz for the reminder):

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("ActionName"))">@T("Cancel")</a>
```

Or using an action for a different controller:

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"))">@T("Cancel")</a>
```

Comment: thank you for detailed reply but it is saying ystem.web.mvc.htmlhelper<dynamic> does not contain a defination for .ActionLink

Comment: @John: I have not seen that before. What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: ah yes thank you musefan....removing the '#' fixed it. @T is for multiple language- its part of orchard cms

Comment: @John: Perharps [this will help](http://forums.asp.net/t/1337165.aspx/1). More specifically, you need to ensure your web.config contains `<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>` (though this problem is different from your question, so if it doesn't fix it consider asking another question for that particular part of your problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, just set the `href` of the `a` tag to be the previous page. Better still, use [`ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493018%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
<li class="align left">
    @Html.ActionLink(T("Cancel"), "PreviousAction")
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it is telling me system.web.mvc.htmlhelper<dynamic> does not contain a defination for .ActionLink